# How to map 2 routes to the same URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, model-view-controller, routes

I want a webpage to do different things depending on what the webpage accessed before was.

Basically, I know how to make data with ever-lasting persistence. However, my method involves using query strings, but I don't want a second user to be able to access a webpage with query strings that have been created before. So, I am trying to get around this problem by mapping multiple routes to a single url.  Is this possible in C# MVC?

Specifically, whenever I click my link from my view(it can be found below), the route that is called is just the first route that has the url The Search_History_Page. Meaning the route with the corresponding action method is not called.  The_Search_History_Page

Here is my route.config

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace CBCM_Audio_Searcher
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Route_That_Leads_To_The_Home_Page_As_The_First_Page",
                url: "The_Home_Page",
                defaults: new { controller = "First_", action = "Goes_To_The_Home_Page_As_The_First_Page"}
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Route_That_Leads_To_The_Search_History_Page_As_The_First_Page",

                url: "The_Search_History_Page",
              defaults: new { controller = "First_", action = "Goes_To_The_Search_History_Page_As_The_First_Page", id = 1}
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Route_That_Leads_To_The_Search_History_Page_From_The_Home_Page",
               url: "The_Search_History_Page",
               defaults: new { controller = "First_", action = "Goes_To_The_Search_History_Page_From_The_Home_Page", id=0 }
           );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics; 

namespace CBCM_Audio_Searcher.Controllers
{
    public class First_Controller : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Goes_To_The_Home_Page_As_The_First_Page()
        {

            Database_Data_Modifier_And_Extractor  Database_Data_Modifier_And_Extractor=new  Database_Data_Modifier_And_Extractor();  

            if (Database_Data_Modifier_And_Extractor.Checks_If_A_User_Can_Access_The_Website() == false)
            {
                return Redirect("http://www.google.com");  
            }

            else 
            {
                ViewData["User_ID"]=Database_Data_Modifier_And_Extractor.User_ID;         
                return View("The_Home_Page");
            }
        }
        public ActionResult Goes_To_The_Search_History_Page_As_The_First_Page(string User_ID,string DummyVariable, int id)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(id); 
            return View("The_Search_History_Page"); 
        }
        public ActionResult Goes_To_The_Search_History_Page_From_The_Home_Page(string User_ID, string DummyVariable, int id)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(id);
            return View("The_Search_History_Page");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my The_Home_Page_View.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your Search Results", "Goes_To_The_Search_History_Page_From_The_Home_Page", "First_", new { User_ID = ViewData["User_ID"], DummyVariable = "a"}, null)
```

My The_Search_History_Page View is empty.

Comment: action selector can be helpful in such situation.

Comment: I don't think that would help me. I want the url to be the same. Action selectors change the url.

Comment: Would your problem be solved with Attribute Routing? The idea is you can use query string params as route criteria. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx?PageIndex=2

Answer (score 2):

MVC has a feature to specify action name for a method. you can specify name by decorating method with `ActionNameAttribute` and passing new action name as arguement.

So whenever request comes for `/Home/Bar` it will be handed to `MyActionMethod` method for processing.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("Bar")]
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
    {
        return Content("Foo");
    }

    [MyActionSelector]
    [ActionName("Foo")]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return Content("Foo");
    }

    [MyActionSelector]
    [ActionName("Foo")]
    public ActionResult Foo2()
    {
        return Content("Foo2");
    }
}
```

When request comes in MVC will look up for methods based on routing table and `ActionNameAttribute` that will handle the request. When MVC find more then two method for a request it throws `AmbiguousMatchException`.

From a list of methods you can specify which method will process the request by creating custom `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`. When `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` is decorated to any method MVC will execute `IsValidForRequest` before executing method to return response. If `IsValidForRequest` return true, MVC will execute method for returning response. Else MVC will find for other method that match routing criteria.

To create your own attribute you have to extend `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` class and override `IsValidForRequest` method. `IsValidForRequest` method has `controllerContext` and `methodInfo` as input parameter. This method may be called multiple times based on how many method is able to fulfill the request. 
Each time `methodInfo` will have different information about method that should process the request(based on routing table/`ActionNameAttribute`).

```
public class MyActionSelectorAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        // your custom method selection logic goes here
        // select method based on previously searched term
        if (request.QueryString["foo"] != null && methodInfo.Name == "Foo")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (request.QueryString["foo2"] != null && methodInfo.Name == "Foo2")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In our case when request comes for `/Home/Foo` MVC has two method `Foo` and `Foo2` that should process the request. As i said earlier before executing any method to return response MVC will invoke `MyActionSelectorAttribute.IsValidForRequest` for both of methods. For illustration purpose we are grabbing QueryString is and checking

1) if foo is present in query string and method is also Foo then return true (means allow execution for `Foo` method)

2) else if query string contains Foo2 and method is also Foo2 then return true (means allow execution for `Foo2` method)

3) else return false.

Comment: Can somebody explain the above code for me? I think this code might not help me much because I think writing the custom method selection logic is the confusing part.

Comment: @AlexanderKao i have updated answer with explanation.

Comment: I actually figured out a way how to accomplish what I wanted using only basic knowledge. Yeahhhhhhhhhhhhh! Thanks anyways.

Comment: I'll give you a summary of my method of how to make query string urls inaccessible(99% of the time) without obsufacating the url.

Comment: The general idea idea is to create at least two pathways to the url with the query string. In the pathway(s) you want people to be able to access, create an intermediate method that redirects to the action where you want to return your view. The 2nd pathway will access that action I mentioned before directly. In the intermediate method, you tell a database to increase the value of "has this page been accessed before to 1".

Comment: You might have to think about the next part for a couple of hours before getting why it works 99% of the time. At the end of the intermediate method, set the value back to 0! In the action that returns a view, make it so that the view you want to return can only be returned if the value is set to 0! However, before the view is returned, set the value to 1!   

While, this method is not 100% secure. I think it is the only implementation that uses only basics and very little code. Obsfucating doesn't made query string urls inaccessible. It just makes it harder for people to access the website

Comment: @AlexanderKao if you found better way share with community as answer. it helps other